# How to refresh a list of entities (GET) after asynchronous entity creation (POST) with react & redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing the problem how to refresh data with redux in my react component **after an asynchronous POST-Call**. I am already using a redux-middleware which manages my rest calls.

Use-Case:

1. Inside a react component the user creates a new element (send data asynchronous via REST-API to backend).
2. Inside the same react component I have a selectable list which now should also contain the new element (with generated Database-ID).

What`s the best react+redux paradigma to update entity in backend and refresh the depending list afterwards?

Best regards Sven

Comment: Have you tried simply re-firing the list daba load?? Aka using redux saga : `yield put(loadMyList())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your hints I just found the answer.

Redux (with redux-thunk middleware) can handle my case just out of the box.
Just combine both actions inside one "wrapper action".

Redux will asynchronous execute the "wrapper action".
But due to my "await" statements inside the "wrapper action" my POST and GET Request will be called synchronous in the right order and each updates my redux store as needed.

See: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

```js
export const createEntityAndReloadEntities: ICrudPutAction<IEntityProfile> = newEntity => async dispatch => {
      return Promise.all[
     await dispatch({
         type: "CREATE_ENTITY",
         payload: axios.post(apiUrl, newEntity)
       }),
       await dispatch({
         type: "FETCH_ENTITY_LIST",
         payload: axios.get<IEntityProfile>(`${apiUrl}`)
       })];
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

For async operations like making Rest calls, you need a middleware like [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) to dispatch actions based on async response. This is how your create is supposed to work on a high level with a middleware:

1. dispatch the create action with payload
2. middleware will issue the rest call to create the object
3. Based on the response returned, the middleware will dispatch further actions to the store eg. adding the new item to the list.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am already using a middleware in redux. My question was more towards "What is the right place to trigger the refresh".

Comment: your refresh should be in your success cb OR once promise is resolved based on what http client you are using. eg https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition